# How do I call the default deserializer from a custom deserializer in Jackson

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have a problem in my custom deserializer in Jackson. I want to access the default serializer to populate the object I am deserializing into. After the population I will do some custom things but first I want to deserialize the object with the default Jackson behavior.

This is the code that I have at the moment.

```
public class UserEventDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<User> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7923585097068641765L;

  public UserEventDeserializer() {
    super(User.class);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
    User deserializedUser = null;
    deserializedUser = super.deserialize(jp, ctxt, new User()); 
    // The previous line generates an exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    // Because there is no implementation of the deserializer.
    // I want a way to access the default spring deserializer for my User class.
    // How can I do that?

    //Special logic

    return deserializedUser;
  }

}
```

What I need is a way to initialize the default deserializer so that I can pre-populate my POJO before I start my special logic.

When calling deserialize from within the custom deserializer It seems the method is called from the current context no matter how I construct the serializer class. Because of the annotation in my POJO. This causes a Stack Overflow exception for obvious reasons.

I have tried initializing a `BeanDeserializer` but the process is extremely complex and I haven't managed to find the right way to do it. I have also tried overloading the `AnnotationIntrospector` to no avail, thinking that it might help me ignore the annotation in the `DeserializerContext`. Finally it seams I might have had some success using `JsonDeserializerBuilders` although this required me to do some magic stuff to get hold of the application context from Spring. I would appreciate any thing that could lead me to a cleaner solution for example how Can I construct a deserialization context without reading the `JsonDeserializer` annotation.

Comment: No. Those approaches will not help: the problem is that you will need a fully constructed default deserializer; and this requires that one gets built, and then your deserializer gets access to it. `DeserializationContext` is not something you should either create or change; it will be provided by `ObjectMapper`. `AnnotationIntrospector`, likewise, won't be of help in getting access.

Comment: How did you end up doing it in the end?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure but I am certain the answer below helped me. I am currently not in the possession of the code that we wrote if you do find a solution please post it here for others.

Comment: It is amazing to me how this was asked in 2013, and in the year of our lord 2022 there still is no sane solution for such an incredibly common requirement.

Comment: @kaqqao I agree. I didn't expect the framework to even be in use any more.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

As StaxMan already suggested you can do this by writing a `BeanDeserializerModifier` and registering it via `SimpleModule`. The following example should work:

```
public class UserEventDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<User> implements ResolvableDeserializer
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7923585097068641765L;

  private final JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer;

  public UserEventDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer)
  {
    super(User.class);
    this.defaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
  }

  @Override public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    User deserializedUser = (User) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt);

    // Special logic

    return deserializedUser;
  }

  // for some reason you have to implement ResolvableDeserializer when modifying BeanDeserializer
  // otherwise deserializing throws JsonMappingException??
  @Override public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException
  {
    ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
  {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier()
    {
      @Override public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer)
      {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == User.class)
          return new UserEventDeserializer(deserializer);
        return deserializer;
      }
    });


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    User user = mapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), User.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already solved this in another way but I will look into your solution when i have more time.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same but with a `JsonSerializer` ? I have several serializers but they have code on common so i want to generify it. I try to directly call The serializer but The result isn't unwrapped in the JSON result (each call of serializer create a new object)

Comment: @herau `BeanSerializerModifier`, `ResolvableSerializer` and `ContextualSerializer` are the matching interfaces to use for serialization.

Comment: Is this applicable for EE edition containers (Wildfly 10)? I get JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

Comment: The question uses `readTree()` but the answer does not. What is the advantage of this approach versus the one [posted by Derek Cochran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123297/14731)? Is there a way to make this work with `readTree()`?

Comment: @PabloJomer Do you by any chance still remember what approach you ended up using? Perhaps one of the other answers offered here?

Comment: I'm sorry as I have previously stated I don't have access to the code any more. And I haven't been working with Jackson since.

Comment: It is really nice, but is it possible to do something similar with jackson 1.x? I have to work on a legacy project with jackson 1.9.2, and that `SimpleModule` didn't have default constructor, neither `setDeserializerModifier()` method in the old times. Or any idea where can I find legacy jackson documentation?

Comment: Implementing `resolve` is not necessary if you use a `DelegatingDeserializer` as base class - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938316/1523648)

Comment: Two important notes: 1- As oberlies said in his answer, registering the module is mutual exclusive with the @JsonDeserializer annotation, if you keep the annotation you will get "Missing 0 arg constructor" (something like this) error.
2 - The conditional in the modifySerializer method is actually VERY necessary (even if you are using the mapper just for your class), otherwise you start getting JVM level errors about modules and loaders that have nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 30):

The `DeserializationContext` has a `readValue()` method you may use. This should work for both the default deserializer and any custom deserializers you have.

Just be sure to call `traverse()` on the `JsonNode` level you want to read to retrieve the `JsonParser` to pass to `readValue()`.

```
public class FooDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<FooBean> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FooDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public FooDeserializer(Class<FooBean> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public FooBean deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        FooBean foo = new FooBean();
        foo.setBar(ctxt.readValue(node.get("bar").traverse(), BarBean.class));
        return foo;
    }

}
```

Comment: DeserialisationContext.readValue() does not exist, that is a method of ObjectMapper

Comment: this solution is working well, however you might need to call nextToken() if you deserialize a value class e.g. Date.class

Comment: Your solution is the most elegant one.You are delegating serialization dispatching of BarBean.class to Jackson. This is nice, you can make your deserializers small, re-usable, and testable. I believe instead of JsonNode.traverse() you should be calling JsonNode.traverse(codec) to pass on existing deserializers codec.

Answer (score 20):

I found an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51927577/14731 which is much more readable than the accepted answer.

```
public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        User user = jp.readValueAs(User.class);
         // some code
         return user;
      }
```

It really doesn't get easier than this.

Comment: Hi Gili! Thanks for it I'm hoping that people find this answer and have time to validate it. I am no longer in a position to do so there for I can not accept the answer at this time. If I see that people do say this is a possible solution I will of course guide them towards it. It may also be that this is not possible for all versions. Still thanks for sharing.

Comment: Does not compile with Jackson 2.9.9. JsonParser.readTree() does not exist.

Comment: @ccleve Looks like a simple typo. Fixed.

Comment: Can confirm that this works with Jackson 2.10, thanks!

Comment: I don't get how this works, this results in a `StackOverflowError`, since Jackson will use the same serializer again for `User`...

Comment: @john16384, it depends on the use case.  If you want to use another registered deserailizer, and modify the result, then it should work.  If you use the same deserializer, you will have to do a work around like in the first answer, to get the original deserializer.

Answer (score 14):

Along the lines of what [Tomáš Záluský has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43213711/1026353), in cases where using `BeanDeserializerModifier` is undesirable you can construct a default deserializer yourself using `BeanDeserializerFactory`, although there is some extra setup necessary. In context, this solution would look like so:

```
public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
    User deserializedUser = null;

    DeserializationConfig config = ctxt.getConfig();
    JavaType type = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(User.class);
    JsonDeserializer<Object> defaultDeserializer = BeanDeserializerFactory.instance.buildBeanDeserializer(ctxt, type, config.introspect(type));

    if (defaultDeserializer instanceof ResolvableDeserializer) {
        ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
    }

    JsonParser treeParser = oc.treeAsTokens(node);
    config.initialize(treeParser);

    if (treeParser.getCurrentToken() == null) {
        treeParser.nextToken();
    }

    deserializedUser = (User) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(treeParser, context);

    return deserializedUser;
}
```

Comment: This works like a dream with Jackson 2.9.9. It doesn't suffer from a StackOverflowError like the other example given.

Comment: This is the only solutions that lets me to export my DTOs with some extra versioning logic. Module approach requires to register in all ObjectMappers (Hibernate uses custom ObjectMapper for example). Converters don't work with generic types. Hack with additional class is a little bit ugly. So current seems the best.

Comment: This should be in Jackson implementation.
Amazing! thanks 

Answer (score 11):

If it is possible for you to declare extra User class then you can implement it just using annotations

```
// your class
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserEventDeserializer.class)
public class User {
...
}

// extra user class
// reset deserializer attribute to default
@JsonDeserialize
public class UserPOJO extends User {
}

public class UserEventDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<User> {

  ...
  @Override
  public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    // specify UserPOJO.class to invoke default deserializer
    User deserializedUser = jp.ReadValueAs(UserPOJO.class);
    return deserializedUser;

    // or if you need to walk the JSON tree

    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
    // specify UserPOJO.class to invoke default deserializer
    User deserializedUser = mapper.treeToValue(node, UserPOJO.class);

    return deserializedUser;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yup. The only approach that worked for me. I was getting StackOverflowErrors because of a recursive call to the deserializer.

Comment: Although this is some kind of hack it allows to use the default serializer for the know fields, while you still have access to the unknown ones. Thus, this can be used to read a csv with columns that should be deserialized to a Map (or a nested object). For example:
 ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
 JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
 User deserializedUser = mapper.treeToValue(node, UserPOJO.class);
 String userName = node.get("user.name").asText();
deserializedUser.setUserName(userName);
return deserializedUser;

Comment: @Bill you don't need the cast to ObjectMapper, treeToValue is inherited

Answer (score 9):

There are couple of ways to do this, but to do it right involves bit more work. Basically you can not use sub-classing, since information default deserializers need is built from class definitions.

So what you can most likely use is to construct a `BeanDeserializerModifier`, register that via `Module` interface (use `SimpleModule`). You need to define/override `modifyDeserializer`, and for the specific case where you want to add your own logic (where type matches), construct your own deserializer, pass the default deserializer you are given.
And then in `deserialize()` method you can just delegate call, take the result Object.

Alternatively, if you must actually create and populate the object, you can do so and call overloaded version of `deserialize()` that takes third argument; object to deserialize into.

Another way that might work (but not 100% sure) would be to specify `Converter` object (`@JsonDeserialize(converter=MyConverter.class)`). This is a new Jackson 2.2 feature.
In your case, Converter would not actually convert type, but simplify modify the object: but I don't know if that would let you do exactly what you want, since the default deserializer would be called first, and only then your `Converter`.

Comment: My answer still stands: you need to let Jackson construct the default deserializer to delegate to; and have to find a way to "override" it. `BeanDeserializerModifier` is the callback handler that allows that.

Answer (score 6):

You are bound to fail if you try to create your custom deserializer from scratch.

Instead, you need to get hold of the (fully configured) default deserializer instance through a custom `BeanDeserializerModifier`, and then pass this instance to your custom deserializer class:

```
public ObjectMapper getMapperWithCustomDeserializer() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
        @Override
        public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config,
                    BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) 
            if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == User.class) {
                return new UserEventDeserializer(defaultDeserializer);
            } else {
                return defaultDeserializer;
            }
        }
    });
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);

    return objectMapper;
}
```

Note: This module registration replaces the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation, i.e. the `User` class or `User` fields should no longer be annotated with this annotation.

The custom deserializer should then be based on a `DelegatingDeserializer` so that all methods delegate, unless you provide an explicit implementation:

```
public class UserEventDeserializer extends DelegatingDeserializer {

    public UserEventDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegatingInstance(JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegate) {
        return new UserEventDeserializer(newDelegate);
    }

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {
        User result = (User) super.deserialize(p, ctxt);

        // add special logic here

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It failed for me with missing non-arg constructor: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class RecordDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor. And super(delegatee) constructor requires non null argument.

Comment: The "has no default (no arg) constructor" is because you've left over the @JsonDeserializer annotation. Registering the module is mutually exclusive with the annotation

Answer (score 1):

I was not ok with using `BeanSerializerModifier` since it forces to declare some behavioral changes in central `ObjectMapper` rather than in custom deserializer itself and in fact it is parallel solution to annotating entity class with `JsonSerialize`. If you feel it the similar way, you might appreciate my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43213463/653539

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short solution using an additional instance of the default ObjectMapper

```
private static final ObjectMapper DEFAULT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper(); // create additional default mapper instance without customization

public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    MyObject object = DEFAULT_MAPPER.readValue(p, MyObject.class);
    // do whatever you want 
    return object;
}
```

**EDIT: Regarding the discussion in the comments: Having an additional ObjectMapper is a performance overhead. If you care about performance, go with another answer.**

And please: There is really no need to use any String value or something else. All needed information are given by JsonParser, so use it.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest solution I've found, but having to create a whole new `ObjectMapper` just to get the default behavior back seems wrong.

Comment: You can make the object mapper a static final  instance.

Comment: It seems like what I need instead of ObjectMapper is "my object mapper without this custom deserializer installed", so that I still pick up other customizations.

Comment: This is definitely not the right answer, as creating a new `ObjectMapper` is always expensive

Comment: @FrancescoGuardiani Check my comment above, you can make the ObjectMapper a final static... I will edit the answer.

Comment: Still, this solution is creating two separate object mappers, so it's error prone as you might need inside this additional mapper to register other custom ser/de for the objects nested within `MyObject`. I think the best solution that works for all is https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938316/2399055

Comment: I see you are fighting this answer. But I do not see the problem in having multiple Object mappers (1 default, 1 custom). Maybe one needs different mappers for different locations, then you can also have multiple custom mappers. It's up to the programmer to handle those instances. I want to provide an alternative answer, and this is one. If someone does not care about performance and just wants something simple to read, why not go with this simple solution, (adjusted code to make it clearer it's a new instance of a default mapper)

Answer (score 1):

Using `BeanDeserializerModifier` works well, but if you need to use `JsonDeserialize` there is a way to do it with `AnnotationIntrospector`
like this:

```
ObjectMapper originalMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectMapper copy = originalMapper.copy();//to keep original configuration
copy.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {

            @Override
            public Object findDeserializer(Annotated a) {
                Object deserializer = super.findDeserializer(a);
                if (deserializer == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                if (deserializer.equals(MyDeserializer.class)) {
                    return null;
                }
                return deserializer;
            }
});
```

Now copied mapper will now ignore your custom deserializer (MyDeserializer.class) and use default implementation. You can use it inside `deserialize` method of your custom deserializer to avoid recursion by making copied mapper static or wire it if using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution for me was to just add another bean of `ObjectMapper` and use that to deserialize the object (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032167/varren comment) - in my case I was interested to either deserialize to its id (an int) or the whole object https://stackoverflow.com/a/46618193/986160

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.io.IOException;

public class IdWrapperDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public IdWrapperDeserializer(Class<T> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String json = jp.readValueAsTree().toString();
          // do your custom deserialization here using json
          // and decide when to use default deserialization using local objectMapper:
          T obj = objectMapper().readValue(json, clazz);

          return obj;
     }
}
```

for each entity that needs to be going through custom deserializer we need to configure it in the global `ObjectMapper` bean of the Spring Boot App in my case (e.g for `Category`):

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
            mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
            mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule")
            .addDeserializer(Category.class, new IdWrapperDeserializer(Category.class))

    mapper.registerModule(testModule);

    return mapper;
}
```