# Jackson serialization and @JsonValue : back to the default behavior

Tags: java, jackson

I have a simple POJO :

```
public class Test {

    private String id;
    private boolean asString;

    // getters and setters

    @JsonValue
    public Object getValue() {
        if (asString) {
            return id;
        }

        // I want to use the default behavior of Jackson but i don't know what to do here
    }
}
```

As you can see, i'm trying to use @JsonValue to make the following behavior :

- If `asString` is `true`, i want to serialize my object as a simple string.
- If `asString` is `false`, i want to serialize my object with the default behavior of Jackson. But i don't know how to do this.

I also tried to make a custom serializer, but i can't reach the "default serializer" of Jackson and call it.

How can i achieve this ? I want to serialize my object as a string on a certain condition but i want to back on the default behavior of Jackson if i want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom deserializer for this class, which inspects `asString` and if it is false, itself calls the default jackson deserializer.

There's a good answer on how to do this at [How do I call the default deserializer from a custom deserializer in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson)