# Default de-serializing behavior when implementing custom DBObject to Java converters

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I am writing custom Serializers and Deserializer for some of my objects by implementing the Converter < FROM ,  TO >  interface.  And while at some points in Serialization I can fall back on the default behavior by simply invoking MappingMongoConverter.convertToMongoType, I am not quite sure how to invoke default Deserialization behavior from my Custom deserializer.

So, once I check the type of object that's being deserialized, and determine that it's one I don't care about (objects are in a Collection), I would like to let the default de-serialization mechanism to deal with the object.  However, I am not quite able to figure out how to invoke a method on something (MappingMongoConverter?) that would do this for me.

Comment: [Take a look at this answer, it may help you...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18405958/247276)