# How to use both JsonTypeInfo and de/serializers for custom handling of polymorphic subtypes?

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson

I have a situation where I need to customize the serialization/deserialization of some JSON. I have simplified this into a readable example. I have a Container class that holds objects implementing MyInterface. In my example ClassA, ClassB, IntegerHolder and StringHolder implement the interface. By adding the @JsonTypeInfo annotation to my interface (and container):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
```

and registering types names for each class, I can successfully read/write these to/from this JSON:

```
{"type":"Container","items":
    [   {"type":"classA","aValue":"AAA"},
        {"type":"classB","bValue":"BBB"},
        {"type":"intHolder","value":123},
        {"type":"stringHolder","value":"abc"} ] }
```

That is all very nice :) My problem is that I want to customize the serialization of the intHolder and stringHolder because they are just wrappers around native types. My JSON will be frequently edited by hand and the primitive types will be used a LOT. So I want to simplify the JSON to:

```
{"type":"Container","items":
    [   {"type":"classA","aValue":"AAA"},
        {"type":"classB","bValue":"BBB"},
        123,
        "abc" ] }
```

I have written a Serializer and Deserializer (extending StdSeralizer and StdDeserializer), put them in a SimpleModule and registered it with the mapper (as illustrated [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson)) and in isolation, it works well. By that, I mean that I can serialize/deserialize the IntegerHolder and StringHolder if they are the only objects in the container, and then only if I remove the @JsonTypeInfo annotation from the interface.  If I do not, then I get this failure while writing to JSON:

```
[main] ERROR MyTests - can't write the Container
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Type id handling not implemented for type MyInterface (by serializer of type MyTests$MyInterfaceSerializer) (through reference chain: Container["items"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1047)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(JsonSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeTypedContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:217)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:201)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:552)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3387)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2747)
    at MyTests.testItemSerializationDeserializationEquality(MyTests.java:51)
    at MyTests.testSerialization(MyTests.java:41)
```

But of course, with the @JsonTypeInfo removed, Jackson doesn't know how to deserialize ClassA and ClassB...so that fails while reading the JSON with:

```
[main] INFO MyTests - {"type":"Container","items":[{"aValue":"AAA"},{"bValue":"BBB"},123,"abc"]}
[main] ERROR MyTests - can't read the Container
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of MyInterface, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@37883b97; line: 1, column: 45] (through reference chain: Container["items"]->Object[][0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:857)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)
    at MyTests$MyInterfaceDeserializer.deserialize(MyTests.java:163)
    at MyTests$MyInterfaceDeserializer.deserialize(MyTests.java:139)
```

I feel like Jackson can do it and I'm close to getting Jackson configured to serialize/deserialize both sets of classes, but so far my attempts have not been fruitful.

Any pointers to get me going in the right direction would be most appreciated...thanks in advance!

Here are the 7 classes in my test example:

MyInterface.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
public interface MyInterface
    {
    }
```

Container.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
public class Container
    {
    public Container()
        {
        }

    public Container(MyInterface... items)
        {
        this.items = items;
        }

    public MyInterface[] getItems()
        {
        return items;
        }

    public void setItems(MyInterface[] items)
        {
        this.items = items;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            if (!(items[i].equals(((Container)obj).items[i])))
                return false;
        return true;
        }

    private MyInterface[] items;
    }
```

MyTests.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.*;
import org.junit.*;
import org.slf4j.*;

import java.io.*;

public class MyTests
    {
    @Test
    public void testSerialization()
        {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.setaValue("AAA");

        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.setbValue("BBB");

        IntegerHolderClass int_holder = new IntegerHolderClass();
        int_holder.setValue(123);

        StringHolderClass string_holder = new StringHolderClass();
        string_holder.setValue("abc");

        // Testing with ONLY the non-customized classes works fine with the @JsonTypeInfo annotation on MyInterface
        // if the custom de/serializers are not registered via the module
//        testItemSerializationDeserializationEquality(new Container(a, b), Container.class);

        // Testing with ONLY the customized classes works fine with the custom de/serializers registered via the module
        // if the @JsonTypeInfo annotation on MyInterface is removed
//        testItemSerializationDeserializationEquality(new Container(int_holder, string_holder), Container.class);

        // This variation tests them all together...doesn't work under either scenario
        testItemSerializationDeserializationEquality(new Container(a, b, int_holder, string_holder), Container.class);
        }

    private void testItemSerializationDeserializationEquality(Object original, Class expected_super_type)
        {
        ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();

        ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
            {
            mapper.writeValue(outstream, original);
            outstream.flush();
            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
            LOG.error("can't write the " + original.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            }

LOG.info(outstream.toString());

        Object copy = null;
        try
            {
            copy = mapper.readValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(outstream.toByteArray()), expected_super_type);
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            LOG.error("can't read the " + original.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            }

        Assert.assertNotNull(copy);
        Assert.assertTrue(copy.equals(original));
        }

    private ObjectMapper createMapper()
        {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(ClassA.class, "classA"));
        mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(ClassB.class, "classB"));
        mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(IntegerHolderClass.class, "intHolder"));
        mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(StringHolderClass.class, "stringHolder"));

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier()
            {
            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer)
                {
                if (MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass()))
                    return new MyInterfaceDeserializer(deserializer);
                return deserializer;
                }
            });
        module.setSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier()
            {
            @Override
            public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer)
                {
                if (MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass()))
                    return new MyInterfaceSerializer(serializer);
                return serializer;
                }
            });

        mapper.registerModule(module);


        return mapper;
        }

    static class MyInterfaceSerializer extends StdSerializer<MyInterface> implements ResolvableSerializer
        {
        public MyInterfaceSerializer(JsonSerializer<?> def)
            {
            super(MyInterface.class);
            _default = (JsonSerializer<MyInterface>) def;
            }

        @Override
        public void serialize(MyInterface value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
            {
            if (value instanceof IntegerHolderClass)
                jgen.writeNumber(((IntegerHolderClass) value).getValue());
            else if (value instanceof StringHolderClass)
                jgen.writeString(((StringHolderClass) value).getValue());
            else
                _default.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
            }

        @Override
        public void resolve(SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException
            {

            }

        private final JsonSerializer<MyInterface> _default;
        }

    static class MyInterfaceDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyInterface> implements ResolvableDeserializer
        {
        public MyInterfaceDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> def)
            {
            super(MyInterface.class);
            _default = def;
            }

        @Override
        public MyInterface deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException
            {
            TreeNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
            if (node instanceof TextNode)
                {
                StringHolderClass holder = new StringHolderClass();
                holder.setValue(((TextNode) node).textValue());
                return holder;
                }
            else if (node instanceof IntNode)
                {
                IntegerHolderClass holder = new IntegerHolderClass();
                holder.setValue(((IntNode) node).intValue());
                return holder;
                }
            return (MyInterface) _default.deserialize(parser, context);
            }

        @Override
        public void resolve(DeserializationContext context) throws JsonMappingException
            {
//            ((ResolvableDeserializer)_default).resolve(context);
            }

        private final JsonDeserializer<?> _default;
        }


    final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTests.class);
    }
```

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA implements MyInterface
    {
    public String getaValue()
        {
        return _aValue;
        }

    public void setaValue(String aValue)
        {
        _aValue = aValue;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
        return obj instanceof ClassA && _aValue.equals(((ClassA)obj)._aValue);
        }

    private String _aValue;
    }
```

ClassB.java

```
public class ClassB implements MyInterface
    {
    public String getbValue()
        {
        return _bValue;
        }

    public void setbValue(String bValue)
        {
        _bValue = bValue;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
        return obj instanceof ClassB && _bValue.equals(((ClassB)obj)._bValue);
        }

    private String _bValue;
    }
```

StringHolderClass.java

```
public class StringHolderClass implements MyInterface
    {
    public String getValue()
        {
        return _value;
        }

    public void setValue(String value)
        {
        _value = value;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
        return obj instanceof StringHolderClass && _value.equals(((StringHolderClass)obj)._value);
        }

    private String _value;
    }
```

IntegerHolderClass.java

```
public class IntegerHolderClass implements MyInterface
    {
    public int getValue()
        {
        return _value;
        }

    public void setValue(int value)
        {
        _value = value;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
        return obj instanceof IntegerHolderClass && _value.equals(((IntegerHolderClass)obj)._value);
        }

    private Integer _value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Custom deserializer for `MyInterface` and then you do not need the JsonTypeInfo - all the logic will be in the deserializer.
2. You can try and have `IntegerHolder` and `StringHolder` implement another interface let's say `Holder` and change the `JsonTypeInfo` annotation to:

   `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", defaultImpl=Holder.class)`

   And for Holder.class specify a deserializer.

Comment: I had to reject #1 already because others will be extending MyInterface and they should not need to write/edit the de/serializers...they should be able to rely on Jackson to do it for them.

Comment: I am trying #2 and that serializes correctly. However, upon deserialization, it fails when looking for the 'type' parameter to determine the type to deserialize. I feel like I should be overriding deserializeWithType() in my HolderClassDeserializer because I did that in the serializer. So that is what I'm trying now. Thanks!