# JsonParser.readTree() returns null after using JsonParser in for default deserializer in jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

The title is not define the problem good so here is the prblem description.

I used a custom deserializer in jackson for my purpose.i need to use the defaul deserializer in my custom deserializer and change some fields in it.i did it based on [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405958) and here is my method:

```
public Test deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException{

    Test test = (Test)this.defaultDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt); 

    JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);

    // The rest of the code use node to change is some fields.

}
```

My Problem is when is use default deserializer the node object will be null and i can't use it to fetch other fields from json object.
do you have any idea how can i fix this problem?

Comment: could you ever solve this?