# Injecting json property based on condition using Jackson

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I have a json format which I am converting into Java Object Model using `Jackson API`. I am using `Jaxsonxml` 2.1.5 parser. The json response is as shown below.

```
 {
   "response": {
   "name": "states",
   "total-records": "1",
   "content": {
     "data": {
       "name": "OK",
       "details": {
         "id": "1234",
         "name": "Oklahoma"
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Now json response format has changed. If the `total-records` is `1` the `details` will be an object with `id` and `name` attributes. But if the `total-records` is more than `1` then the `details` will be an array of object like below:

```
    {
      "response": {
        "name": "states",
        "total-records": "4",
        "content": {
          "data": {
            "name": "OK",
            "details": [
              {
                "id": "1234",
                "name": "Oklahoma"
              },
              {
                "id": "1235",
                "name": "Utah"
              },
              {
                "id": "1236",
                "name": "Texas"
              },
              {
                "id": "1237",
                "name": "Arizona"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

My Java Mapper class looks like below with earlier `json` response.

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class MapModelResponseList {

      @JsonProperty("name")
      private String name;

      @JsonProperty("total-records")
      private String records;

      @JsonProperty(content")
      private Model model;

      public Model getModelResponse() {
        return model;
      }

      public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
      }
    }
```

Client Code

```
    package com.test.deserializer;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com..schema.model.Person;

    public class TestClient {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String response1="{\"id\":1234,\"name\":\"Pradeep\"}";
            TestClient client = new TestClient();
            try {
                Person response = client.readJSONResponse(response1, Person.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public <T extends Object> T readJSONResponse(String response, Class<T> type) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
            T result = null;
            try {
                result = mapper.readValue(response, type);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return (T) result;
        }

    }
```

Now based on the `total-records` how to handle to mapping to either a `Model` or list of `Model` Object. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom deserializer. The idea is to mix and match object processing with tree processing. Parse objects where possible but use the tree (`JSONNode`) for custom handling.

On the `MapModelResponseList`, remove the `records` property and add a `List<Data>` array where `Data` is just a holder class for the id/name pairs. You can get the total records by returning the size of this list.

In the deserializer, do the following:

```
public final class MapModelDeserializer extends BeanDeserializer {
   public MapModelDeserializer(BeanDeserializerBase src) {
    super(src);
   }

  protected void handleUnknownProperty(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, Object beanOrClass, String propName) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if ("content".equals(propName)) {
      MapModelResponseList response = (MapModelResponseList) beanOrClass;

      // this probably needs null checks!
      JsonNode details = (JsonNode) jp.getCodec().readTree(jp).get("data").get("details");

      // read as array and create a Data object for each element
      if (details.isArray()) {
        List<Data> data = new java.util.ArrayList<Data>(details.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) {
           Data d = jp.getCodec().treeToValue(details.get(i), Data.class);
           data.add(d);
        }

        response.setData(data);
      }
      // read a single object
      else {
         Data d = jp.getCodec().treeToValue(details, Data.class);
         response.setData(java.util.Collections.singletonList(d));
      }

    super.handleUnknownProperty(jp, ctxt, beanOrClass, propName);
}
```

Note that you do not implement `deserialize()` - the default implementation is used to create the `MapModelResponseList` as normal. `handleUknownProperty()` is used to deal with the `content` element. Other data you don't care about is ignored due to `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` in the super call.

Comment: I am getting an Error stating `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class com.test.deserializer.CustomDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor` when using the above approach.

Comment: I tried with your approach. But still no luck. Let me know if I my client code is correct. I am still getting the same exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class com.test.deserializer.CustomDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor`

Comment: which version of jaxson are you using. I am always getting the same error `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class com.test.deserializer.CustomDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor`.

Comment: If you are using `@JsonDeserialize`, I don't see an easy way to to create a BeanDeserializerBase with a no arg constructor. You probably need to create the deserializer in a custom module - see [the answer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson).

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but I solve it in a different way. It can work by catching it in `Object` like this:

```java
    @JsonProperty("details")
    public void setDetails(Object details) {
        if (details instanceof List) {
            setDetails((List) details);
        } else if (details instanceof Map) {
            setDetails((Map) details);
        }
    }

    public void setDetails(List details) {
        // your list handler here
    }

    public void setDetails(Map details) {
       // your map handler here
    }
```