# Conditional JSON response creation using Java POJO for rest service

Tags: java, json, rest

I am creating a rest service and providing json to our consumer.
I have two fields cardType, cardDetails ( i have more fields but these are what relevant).

If cardType is credit card then only I want to send another field cardDetails in json.

If cardtype is something else, Then I don't want to send card details(not even empty data) .
I am not getting how can i achieve solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injecting json property based on condition using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684201/injecting-json-property-based-on-condition-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

Which language do you use? 
In spring framework you can do it very easy. 
You can add if condition in your controller.

```
    @RestController
public class YourController {
    @Autowired
    YourRepository yourRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/creaditCardsInfo")
    public String sendCreditCardToCustomer(@RequestParam(value = "creditCardType", defaultValue = "none") String cardType,@RequestParam(value = "cardDetails", default = "someInfo") String cardDetails) {
if("credit".equals(cardType.trim()) && !(cardDetails.isEmpty())){
return new RequredCreditInfoObject(); 
}
```

if you use maven your pom.xml should contain required libs

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Data (if We are going to use Repositories, Hibernate, etc...) -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for JSon marshaling  --> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Good luck,