# Deserializing json embedded node as value into Map using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Dear folks I need you advice.

I'm, trying to implement custom `Jackson` deserializer for maps but having difficulties with it. As an input data I have the following json:

```
{
    "someMap": {
        "one_value": "1",
        "another_value: "2"
    },
    "anotherMap": "{\"100000000\": 360000,\"100000048\": 172800,\"100000036\": 129600,\"100000024\": 86400,\"100000012\": 43200}"
}
```

As you can see in the second case it has json map inside node value(I'm doing it in that way by intention. Because I want to replace the value from env variable: `"anotherMap": "${SOME_MAP:-{\"100000000\": 360000,\"100000048\": 172800,\"100000036\": 129600,\"100000024\": 86400,\"100000012\": 43200}}"`). As I understand I have to differentiate somehow between that 2 maps deserialization flows. So for the first map I need to use default one map deserializer for the second one the custom one to have properly parsed map from the value. At the moment I wrote that code to do that:

```
// invokation code
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ConfigModule()).readValue(is, ConfigModuleTestConfigWrapper.class);

// module code
public class ConfigModule extends SimpleModule {

@Override
public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
    super.setupModule(context);
    context.addDeserializers(new Deserializers.Base() {

          @Override
          public JsonDeserializer<?> findMapDeserializer(MapType type, DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                         KeyDeserializer keyDeserializer, TypeDeserializer elementTypeDeserializer,
                                                         JsonDeserializer<?> elementDeserializer) throws JsonMappingException {
              return new MapPropertyDeserializer(type);
          }
    });
}

private static class MapPropertyDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<Map<String, Integer>> {
    MapPropertyDeserializer(MapType type) {
        super(type);
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        if (node == null || node.isContainerNode()) {
              // return <default jackson deserializer>
        }
        System.out.println("isContainerNode ?: " + node.isContainerNode());
        System.out.println("isValueNode ?: " + node.isValueNode());
        // some parsing flow goes below
        JsonNode valueNode = node.get(1);
        valueNode.asText();
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}

// bean description
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class ConfigSubstitutorModuleTestConfigWrapper {

  private final Map<String, String> someMap;
  private final Map<String, Integer> anotherMap;

  @JsonCreator
  public ConfigSubstitutorModuleTestConfigWrapper(
          @JsonProperty("someMap") Map<String, String> someMap,
          @JsonProperty("anotherMap") Map<String, Integer> anotherMap

  ) {
      this.someMap = someMap;
      this.anotherMap = anotherMap;
  }

  public Map<String, String> getSomeMap() {
      return someMap;
  }
  public Map<String, Integer> getAnotherMap() {
      return anotherMap;
  }
}
```

The problem is(as I understand:)) that I don't know how to return default map deserializer from the deserialize method.

Does anybody have any clue what I could do there to achieve desired goal ?

Comment: Couldn't you rather fix the part that generates this ugly JSON string inside JSON? That is the part that looks broken to me.

Comment: I can't do that. The idea here is to substitute that ugly json with value from environment variable like that `"anotherMap": "${SOME_MAP:-{\"100000000\": 360000,\"100000048\": 172800,\"100000036\": 129600,\"100000024\": 86400,\"100000012\": 43200}}"`. 

So I'm doing it by intention.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson

Comment: @SharonBenAsher mm it's quite close to what I want but the difference is  we have some special type like `User.class` to decide on proper deserizler. In my case I only have to somehow consider the node value not his type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally accepted that **Solution** to resolve it:

1) Create deserializer class:

```
 /**
 * The target of that deserializer is to do two-step deserialization.
 * At first it just reads string and then does second deserialization in the proper {@link Map} type once string substitution done.
 * <p>
 * Note! In order to get object mapper reference you have to set it first on object mapper initialization stage:
 * </p>
 * <pre>
 *     objectMapper.setInjectableValues(new InjectableValues.Std().addValue(OBJECT_MAPPER_VALUE_ID, objectMapper));
 * </pre>
 */
public class ValueAsMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map> implements ContextualDeserializer {
    public static final String OBJECT_MAPPER_VALUE_ID = "objectMapper";
    static final String VALUE_PREFIX = "$|";
    static final String VALUE_SUFFIX = "|";

    private JavaType keyType;
    private JavaType valueType;

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(final DeserializationContext ctxt,
                                                final BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        JavaType filedType = property.getType();
        this.keyType = filedType.getKeyType();
        this.valueType = filedType.getContentType();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Map deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        // Can't use constructor init there because of intention to use that deserializer using annotation
        // Also such tricky thing as 'injectable values' was used cause of no way to get the reference to object mapper from deserialization context out of the box
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) ctxt.findInjectableValue(OBJECT_MAPPER_VALUE_ID, null, null);
        final Optional<String> substitutedValue = Substitutor.create(jp, VALUE_PREFIX, VALUE_SUFFIX).substitute();
        MapType mapType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, keyType, valueType);
        return objectMapper.readValue(substitutedValue.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Failed to parse the value as map")), mapType);
    }
}
```

2) Mark bean field to use that deserializer:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ValueAsMapDeserializer.class)
private final Map<String, Integer> anotherMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do deserialization in two steps:

```
package stack43844461;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class HowToConvertJsonStringToMap {

    @Test
    public void json() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        String jsonInString = "{\"someMap\":"
                        + " {\"one_value\": \"1\","
                        + "\"another_value\": \"2\"},"
                        + "\"anotherMap\": "
                        + "\"{\\\"100000000\\\": 360000,"
                        + "\\\"100000048\\\": 172800,"
                        + "\\\"100000036\\\": 129600,"
                        + "\\\"100000024\\\": 86400,"
                        + "\\\"100000012\\\": 43200}\"}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Step 1: Read everything into one object. 
        Map<String, Object> all = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Map.class);
        // Step 2: Get your "normal" data into one object
        Map<String, Object> someMap=(Map<String, Object>) all.get("someMap");
        // Step 3: Get your "embedded" data from your object
        String anotherMapStr = (String) all.get("anotherMap");
        // Step 4: Deserialize embedded data
        Map<String, Object> anotherMap = mapper.readValue(anotherMapStr, Map.class);
        System.out.println(anotherMap);
        System.out.println(someMap);
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
{100000000=360000, 100000048=172800, 100000036=129600, 100000024=86400, 100000012=43200}
{one_value=1, another_value=2}
```

Comment: Yes it might would have worked in my case. But I have to work with module that will be registered for objectMapper so I need to do that in deserializer also rather than having `jsonInString` I have fields in POJO with type `Map` and don't know exact field name like `anotherMap `