# Jackson, how can I use default deserializer in custom one

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class which is annotated with

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
```

now I would like to use also default deserializer in CustomDeserializer.class

```
@Override
public CustomObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
{
  if(someCondition){
     return useDefaultDeserialization(jp); // default
  } else {
     return new ObjectMapper().readValue(jp..., CustomObject.class); // custom
  }
}
```

How can I invoke default deserializer?

Comment: You should be able to find an answer here: [How do I call the default deserializer from a custom deserializer in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson)

Comment: No, unfortunately this does not work. I'm getting StackOverflowError because all the time custom deserializer is invoked when -> 
mapper.readValue((String) jp.getCurrentLocation().getSourceRef(), CustomObject.class)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you provide a _concrete_ example?

Comment: @PDS , check the Accepeted Answer in the link Ryan posted.

Comment: I can't believe this is as difficult as it is...