# Overloaded setters on Jackson object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to have an overloaded setter on a Jackson deserializable object. So that depending on the object in that field it deserializes differently.

**Example**

```
public class Thing {
    private MyObject1 object;

    public MyObject1 getObject() {
        return object;

    public void setObject(MyObject1 object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void setObject(MyObject2 object) {
        this.object = translate1To2(object);
    }
}
```

If this is not possible, would someone offer me an alternative approach? My concern is that in the simple case where there is only one setter, Jackson doesn't have to choose which object to deserialize the JSON as, so not sure if it even can.

UPDATE: The above gives a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "object"` as is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call the default deserializer from a custom deserializer in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you cannot actually overload setters like this in Jackson, my solution was as follows:

I made a deserializer to translate `MyObject2` to `MyObject1` and had one setter, so my class looked like this:

```
public class Thing {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyObjectDeserializer.class)
    private MyObject1 object;

    public MyObject1 getObject() {
        return object;

    public void setObject(MyObject1 object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way, I think is add a Custom Deserialization class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ThingDeserializer.class)
public class Thing {
...
}
```

Example of deserialization here
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Then, your bean will be ever clean, and you make your own JSON as you want to have

Comment: Very similar, see my eventual solution below.