# jackson - Deserialize object with a list of polymorphic types

Tags: java, json, jackson

I think it's best to explain with an example.

I have a JSON object I want to deserialize that contains a list of type interface and which type is in the list, but I'm not sure how to get the deserializer to determine which concrete type is in the list:

**Type to deserialize**

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyEnum type; // A or B
    private List<Parent> objects;
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface Parent
```

**Children**

```
public ChildA implements Parent
public ChildB implements Parent
```

I know I can use the type with `JsonSubTypes` with the type if it *wasn't* a `List`, such as:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildA.class, name = "A"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildB.class, name = "B")
})
```

And the same thing if `type` is inside the Parent type. But is there a way to assist the deserializer in determining the type in the list when the type is outside the `Parent` class? (the list will only ever contain one child type)

Answer (score 1):

Jackson struggles with type erasure on collections with `JsonTypeInfo` (Here's a Jackson Scala [bug report](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/281)). However, arrays are strongly typed so if possible, you could switch to using an array instead. It seems the simplest way.

Alternatively, writing a smart [`JsonDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) capable of instantiating the correct class could be used with the [`@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=...)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html#contentUsing()) annotation. Internally, the deserializer could still fall back to using Jackson's `readValue` method. So it really would be just responsible for choosing the correct type. This [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18313323/4822566) give examples of reverting to standard deserialization from a custom deserializer.

Comment: The only issue I can't seem to work out is using the deserializer with `contentUsage` is that the `type` flag is outside the `Parent` class.