# Jackson rollback parsing for field format is incorrect

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class to which a deserialize a server response:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Card {

double amount;

String cardType;
String cardNumber
... many more properties
}
```

API is not very consistent, so for my request in question I get a string `"$74.50"` which fails obviously to parse to double as is. I can't modify the class as it will probably fail something elsewhere where it's actual double.

Can I make condition for jackson to take the string literally without modifying the class? I think I can do so with custom deserializer on `ObjectMapper` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson), but not sure how to pull it off exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create additional setter for `amount`:

```
@JsonSetter("amount")
public void setAmount(String sAmount) {
    // parse "$74.50" to 74.50 here
    this.amount = parsedAmount;
}
```

It will be called for field like `{"amount": "$74.50"}` and correct set `amount` in your class.