# Jackson: how do I do validation after deserialization?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, introspection, jackson-modules

I'm using [Jackson with Kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/) to serialize and deserialize a variety of Kotlin `data class`es.

My `data class`es are quite simple objects which can easily be serialized and deserialized using the standard Jackson `ObjectMapper`, *except* that I want to ensure that some post-validation is done as part of the deserialization. For example, I want to ensure that `Thing.someField >= 0`:

```kotlin
data class InnerThing(
    val foo: String
);

data class Thing(
    val someField: Int,   // must not be negative
    val innerThing: InnerThing
);
```

The simplest way to implement this would seem to be to override the `StdDeserializer` for the class(es) in question.

```kotlin
class ThingDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Thing>(Thing::class.java) {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Thing {
        // Defer to the superclass to do the actual deserialization
        // DOES NOT WORK because StdDeserializer.deserialize() is abstract
        val t: Thing = super.deserialize(p, ctxt);

        if (thing.someField < 0) {
            throw RuntimeException("someField value must be >= 0");
        }

        return t;
    }
}
```

… but that **does not work** because `StdDeserializer.deserialize()` is abstract. Which leads me to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson). It appears that it's amazingly difficult to defer to the default deserialization behavior from within a custom deserializer.

From what I can tell, the most straightforward way to defer to the default deserialization behavior is to create an *entirely* separate `ObjectMapper` (!!!), use *that* to read the class, and then do the post-validation.

Leading me to this…

```kotlin
class ThingDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Thing>(Thing::class.java) {

    // Create a whole separate ObjectMapper that doesn't override
    // the deserializer for Thing:
    private val defaultMapper = jacksonObjectMapper();

    init {
        // Need to reregister modules for things like ISO8601
        // timestamp parsing:
        defaultMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule());
    }    

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Thing {
        // Use the non-overridden ObjectMapper to deserialize the object:
        val t: Thing = defaultMapper.readValue(p, Thing::class.java);

        // ... and then do validation afterwards
        if (thing.someField < 0) {
            throw RuntimeException("someField value must be >= 0");
        }

        return t;
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    mapper.registerModule(
        SimpleModule().apply {
          addDeserializer(Thing::class.java, ThingDeserializer()) 
        }
    );

    val test: Thing = mapper.readValue("""{
      "someField": -1,
      "innerThing": { "foo": "bar" }
    }""");
}
```

This **does** work; it throws a `RuntimeException` for the unwanted value of `someField` in the test case.

## This seems wrong

Is the above *really* a reasonable way to do this validation?

It has a very bad code smell. I'm creating a whole new `ObjectMapper`, and I have to re-register modules for things like timestamp deserialization.

## Question

It feels like there *must be* a saner, less redundant way to deserialize a Kotlin `data class` (or Java POJO) and then do post-validation of the contents of the object, without rewriting the deserialization machinery entirely.

Is there? I can't figure out a simple way to defer to the default deserialization behavior of `ObjectMapper` from within the deserializer.

Comment: Does it make sense to have instance of `Thing` with negative `someField` if it was created not via deserialization? Maybe you just need to change this field type to [UInt](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-u-int/) or move this check to `init` block?

Comment: Thanks @МихаилНафталь. In this case, because of a fairly complex versioning of the whole data structure, included nested elements therein, it would be easier to validate the whole structure in one piece, rather than as the individual `data class`es get instantiated. But yeah… some of the validation can be done in the `init` blocks of those classes.

Comment: The simple machinery by @oddbjorn in the answer below allows for quite sane validation (minimal code). Once the required setup is in place, all you need is a `validate()` method in your classes..

Answer (score 4):

For automatic validation during deserialization, using a `@JsonCreator` constructor is probably the most correct way of doing this, but if your data classes have many fields the constructor signature will end up being rather long.

With a bit of leg work you can do this in a fairly clean fashion and still keep your data classes compact and neat. The trick is to hook into Jacksons deserialization process by means of the combination of the `BeanDeserializerModifier`, `StdDelegatingDeserializer` and `Converter` classes. Hooking these up correctly, you can have the `BeanDeserializerModifier` delegate to a `StdDelegatingDeserializer` that calls a `Converter` that validates the deserialization result object before returning it unchanged.

Begin by defining your `Validatable` interface:

```
public interface Validatable {
    void validate();
}
```

And then define the `Converter` class that simply validates:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ValidatingConverter implements Converter<Object, Object> {

    private final JavaType type;

    public ValidatingConverter(JavaType type) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.type = type);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Validatable validatable) {
            validatable.validate();
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Then, the `ValidatingConverter` can be used by a `StdDelegatingDeserializer`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDelegatingDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ValidatingBeanDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(beanDesc.getType(), deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyEnumDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, JavaType type, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(type, deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyReferenceDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, ReferenceType type, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(type, deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyArrayDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, ArrayType type, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(type, deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyCollectionDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, CollectionType type, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(type, deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyCollectionLikeDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, CollectionLikeType type, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(type, deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyMapDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, MapType type, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(type, deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyMapLikeDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, MapLikeType type, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        return createDelegate(type, deserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyDeserializer modifyKeyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, JavaType type, KeyDeserializer deserializer) {
        return new KeyDeserializer() {
            @Override
            public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                final var deserializedKey = deserializer.deserializeKey(key, ctxt);
                if (deserializedKey instanceof Validatable validatable) {
                    validatable.validate();
                }
                return deserializedKey;
            }
        };
    }

    private JsonDeserializer<?> createDelegate(JavaType type, JsonDeserializer<?> target) {
        return new StdDelegatingDeserializer<>(new ValidatingConverter(type), type, target);
    }
}
```

Then, `ValidatingBeanDeserializerModifier` can be used from a Jackson module:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class ValidationModule extends SimpleModule {
    public ValidationModule() {
        this.setDeserializerModifier(new ValidatingBeanDeserializerModifier());
    }
}
```

Finally, we can verify that it all works by first creating a `Validatable` class (or even a record):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Person implements Validatable {

    public String name;
    public int age;
    public Person spouse;
    public Map<String, Person> parents;
    public List<Person> children;

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name, "Person.name must be non-null");
        if (age < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Person.age must be >= 0");
        }
    }
}
```

And run the whole setup in a test class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ValidationModule());
        @Language("JSON") final var json = """
                {
                  "name": "John",
                  "age": 50,
                  "spouse": {
                    "name": "Anne",
                    "age": 50
                  },
                  "parents": {
                    "father": {
                      "name": "Greg",
                      "age": 75
                    },
                    "mother": {
                      "name": "Hilda",
                      "age": 75
                    }
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "Bob",
                      "age": 25
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Wilma",
                      "age": 20
                    }
                  ]
                }""";
        final var person = objectMapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
    }

}
```

Try setting the age of one of JSON `Person` objects to a negative integer and you will get an exception similar to the following: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Person.age must be >= 0 (through reference chain: Person["children"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])`

Jackson version used: `2.12.2`

Answer (score 1):

A general facility for doing things validation has been requested:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2045

although not yet implemented. Presumably this would not be limited to be just annotation-based but would allow pluggable post-processing (plus one can always "fake" annotations by sub-classing `AnnotationIntrospector` anyway).

Beyond this (which is not yet available), for POJOs use of `@JsonCreator` works well if you can pass all properties through it (constructor or factory method). But not so well for validating 3rd party types.