# How to deserialize single json property into multiple Java fields (if possible with converter)

Tags: json, jackson, jackson-databind

Having this class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Result {

    private String positionText;
    private Integer positionNumber;
    .. many many other properties ..
}
```

and deserializing this json:

```
[
    {
        "position": "1",
        .. many many other properties ..
    },
    {
        "position": "FOO",
        .. many many other properties ..
    },
    ..
}
```

how can the `position` json property deserialized into both the `positionText` and `positionNumber` Java fields?

```
public abstract class ResultMixIn {

    @JsonProperty("position")
    abstract String getPositionText();

    @JsonProperty("position")
    abstract Integer getPositionNumber();
}
```

but this gives a:

```
Conflicting getter definitions for property "position": com.example.domain.Result#getPositionText() vs com.example.domain.Result#getPositionNumber()
```

Also changing the abstract getters to setters does not make a difference.

If possible I would like to avoid a fully fledged `ResultDeserializer` extending `StdDeserializer` as the `Result` class has many more properties which I would prefer not to deserialize "by hand".

PS: I'm not concerned about serializing. I'm only deserializing the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to annotate the properties of the `Result` class,
so that Jackson will deserialize the `positionText` property,
but not the `positionNumber`.
You will do the latter by yourself in a taylor-made deserializer.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Result {

    @JsonProperty("position")
    private String positionText;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer positionNumber;
    
    .. many many other properties ..
}
```

By default Jackson would use a `BeanDeserializer` for deserializing `Result` objects.
But you want a slightly modified implementation of this deserializer.

The rest of this answer is largely an adaptation of the accepted answer given to
the question [How do I call the default deserializer from a custom deserializer in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson).

As usual your deserializer extends from `StdDeserializer<Result>`,
but it also implements the  `ResolvableDeserializer` interface.
In  the `deserialize` method most of the work is delegated to the default deserializer
(in this case a `BeanDeserializer`) which we got from Jackson.
We only add a small extra logic for setting the `positionNumber` property
based on the `positionText` property.

```
public class ResultDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Result> implements ResolvableDeserializer {

    private final JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer;

    public ResultDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) {
        super(Result.class);
        this.defaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        if (defaultDeserializer instanceof ResolvableDeserializer) {
            // We need to resolve the default deserializer, or else it won't work properly.
            ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Result deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // let defaultDeserializer do the work:
        Result result = (Result) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);

        // here you do your custom logic:
        String positionText = result.getPositionText();
        if (positionText != null) {
            try {
                result.setPositionNumber(Integer.valueOf(positionText));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                // positionText is not a valid integer
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally you need to tell Jackson that you want the above `ResultDeserializer`
to be used for deserializing `Result` objects.
This is done by the following customization of the `ObjectMapper`,
which will wrap your `ResultDeserializer` around Jackson's
default deserializer, only if a `Result` object is to be deserialized:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule()
            .setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            
                @Override
                public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config,
                        BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
                    if (Result.class == beanDesc.getBeanClass())
                        return new ResultDeserializer(deserializer);  // your deserializer
                    return deserializer;
                }
            }));
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON content as usual, for example:

```
File file = new File("example.json");
List<Result> results = objectMapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<Result>>() {});
```